# How do I solve question 12 in The Impossible Test 2?

Tags: impossible-test-2

On question 12 of the Impossible Test 2 on iOS, it asks you to tap the bills from lowest to highest. It looks like this:
[image]

When I tap one, it disappears. then, when I try to tap the other bill, it makes me lose a life! How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Games Dreams](http://gamesdreams.com/showthread.php?34275-The-Impossible-Test-2-Tap-the-bills-from-lowest-to-highest-Q12), the first step is to tap any bill. Then, turn your device around until the backwards 6 turns into a nine and the words are reversed. Then you should be able to continue!